# Why are there required tags in meta?

Tags: discussion, support, tagging, meta

Every question requires one of the tags [feature-request], [bug], [support], or [discussion]. Why is this so?

Comment: What difficulties has this caused you?

Comment: I am just extremely curious.

Comment: The links below are mostly related to [meta.se], but they might be useful here, too. 
The [corresponding tag-info on Meta Stack Exchange](https://meta.stackexchange.com/tags/required-tags/info) contains a link to [this answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/47634/what-is-meta-stack-exchange-and-how-does-it-work#47640)
And you can find some related discussions, such as: [What is the idea behind required tags here on Meta?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/169212) and ["must include one of these tags -- bug feature-request discussion support"](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/38481)

Comment: I guess that message we all should take from this requirement is that unless the post is not a feature request, a bug report, asking for support in using the main site, or a call for a discussion, then the post is off-topic on meta

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen One can ask for support in using the meta site, too, since there's no Math Meta Meta SE.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The 'obvious' answer is the idea  to structure the various meta sites in a standardized way. What is likely not obvious is that this is actually used beyond what what can be   done with usual  tags.

For example,
a question  tagged as "discussion"  might show up as Hot Meta Post on main, a "bug" question will not but instead it will by brought to the  attention from SE staff.